# What is the term for $ABA^{-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, terminology

If $A, B$ are some matrices such that their products are defined, is there a term to describe pre-multiplication by $A$ and post-multiplication by its inverse ($ABA^{-1}$).

It became particularly useful in applying a change of basis before a linear transformation, then changing back to the original basis. $P_{B \leftarrow B'} [T]_{B'}P_{B' \leftarrow B} = P_{B \leftarrow B'} [T]_{B'}P_{B \leftarrow B'}^{-1} = ABA^{-1}$

I had a linear algebra professor who called it “conjugation”, but I am under the impression that that refers to a complex conjugate.

Comment: Yes, conjugate is the correct term. It is more general, in group theory, where $aba^{-1}$ is called a conjugate of $b.$

Comment: It is often called *conjugation*. In a group $G$, the automorphism given by $b\mapsto aba^{-1}$ is also called *inner automorphism* - see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_automorphism). The group in your context is $GL_n(K)$.

Comment: This instance of conjugation has nothing to do with complex conjugates.  Expect to have terms used in more than one way ("normal").

Comment: The word "conjugate" is very general and applies to many different things in mathematics and outside mathematics, e.g., to conjugate a verb.

Comment: Also called a [similarity transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_similarity).

Comment: @ThomasAndrews The group theory isn't "more general". It is more general in some aspects (maybe even in most aspects), but it is certainly _less_ general in other aspects. In particular, the matrix $B$ doesn't have to be invertible.

Comment: Ah, yes, of course. @Arthur

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few examples of the word *conjugation* in mathematics:

1. Complex conjugation, the change of sign of the imaginary part of a complex number
2. Conjugate (square roots), the change of sign of a square root in an expression
3. Conjugate element (field theory), a generalization of the preceding conjugations to roots of a polynomial of any degree
4. Conjugate transpose, the complex conjugate of the transpose of a matrix
5. Harmonic conjugate in complex analysis
6. Conjugate (graph theory), an alternative term for a line graph, i.e. a graph representing the edge adjacencies of another graph
7. In group theory, various notions are called conjugation:
   Inner automorphism, a type of conjugation homomorphism
8. Conjugation in group theory, related to matrix similarity in linear algebra
9. Conjugation (group theory), the image of an element under the conjugation homomorphisms
10. Conjugate closure, the image of a subgroup under the conjugation homomorphisms
11. Conjugate words in combinatorics; this operation on strings resembles conjugation in groups
12. Isogonal conjugate, in geometry
13. Conjugate gradient method, an algorithm for the numerical solution of particular systems of linear equations
14. Conjugate points, in differential geometry
15. Topological conjugation, which identifies equivalent dynamical systems
16. Convex conjugate, the ("dual") lower-semicontinuous convex function resulting from the Legendre–Fenchel transformation of a "primal" function

Comment: The uses in $1$ and $4$ are referring to the same thing. Might also be worth noting that $2$ is a generalization of $1$.